# pushViewController has weird gradient in UINavigationBar

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

When pushing a new viewcontroller to the stack I see a weird gradient / mask for a second or so and then it clears away[image]

I have a `UINavigationController` that presents a view, that view has an edit button this dismisses the presented view and in the completion handler pushes a new view.

Comment: Please add your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are doing it through xcode 11. And while building it with xcode 11 now it shows new controller in this new overlapping screen modals.
If you want to make it more like full screen then use this code

```
     let changevc = UIViewController() // change this code as this is  your view controller with edit button
     changeVC.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen //or .overFullScreen 
     self.present(changeVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Enjoy!!